# __defineGetter__ in a Firefox extension is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am trying to define a Getter on an XUL iframe in a Firefox extension:

```
// iframe is an XUL iframe element
iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("node", function () {
    return this.nodeName;
});
```

I can access the `iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.HTMLElement.prototype` but `__defineGetter__` is undefined.

`Object.defineProperty` works but this requires to define it for each element created.

Is there a way to use `HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__`? Why is `__defineGetter__` undefined?

Answer (score 1):

> `Object.defineProperty` works but this requires to define it for each element created.

No, you just defined the property on the prototype object:

```
Object.defineProperty(
  iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.HTMLElement.prototype,
  node,
  ...
);
```

> Why is `__defineGetter__` undefined?

As you can read in the [MDN documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter), `__definedGetter__` is not a standard feature of ECMAScript. Furthermore, `HTMLElement` is a **host object** and doesn't have to adhere to the specification.

---

It's an older article, but might still be worth a read: [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Comment: Yes, I've tryed Object.defineProperty(iframe.contentWindow.HTMLElement and worked in a fiddle but however in my extension it did not.

Answer (score 1):

With all the wrappers and expandos that this will likely cause to create and access (compartment/security-boundary wrapper between the chrome context and the content context, DOM element wrapper, maybe other stuff) this might be just a genuine bug.
Also, `__defineGetter__` is non-standard, and should be avoided anyway.

You can use `Object.defineProperty`, and it seems to work when I did a cursory test.

```
Object.defineProperty(iframe.contentWindow.HTMLElement.prototype, "node", {
  "get": function() {
    return this.nodeName;
  }
});
```

Having said this, extending the prototype of built-in objects is strongly discouraged when it is not your own code you're extending in such a way (for compatibility reasons), and may even lead to AMO denying you a full review.

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed on content context but fails in my extension for some reason. Did you tried it in an extension?

Comment: Probably one of all these wrappers just "eats" it.